# Extjs layout hbox in table not visible

Tags: extjs, layout, extjs6, hbox

When I place hbox in table layout items is not visible!

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Hello',
width: 200,    
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 9,
},    
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                html: '123',
            },
        ],
    },
],    
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q1h

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. You are trying to insert a hbox layout inside a table layout without any item. Can you clarify to us what you intend to do in terms of the layout of your app? Here you will find an example of a table layout: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/Ext.layout.container.Table.html

Comment: I see that your table layout has 9 columns. If  what you want to is insert a hbox layout inside a table column, see if this helps https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q22 
Try to clarify what you want so we can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is by setting the `width` of your container:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello',
    width: 500,

    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 9,
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        width: 100,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: '123'
        }, ],
    }, ],

    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1q20)